# BitArray AND operation

Tags: c#

I have created one BitArray program.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BitArray bit1 = new BitArray(4);
    bit1[0] = true;
    bit1[1] = false;
    bit1[2] = true;
    bit1[3] = false;
    for (int a = 0; a < bit1.Count; a++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(bit1[a]);
    }

    bool[] arr = new bool[] { false, true, true, false };
    BitArray bit2 = new BitArray(arr);
    for (int a = 0; a < bit2.Count; a++)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(bit2[a]);
    }

    BitArray bit3 = bit1.And(bit2);
    for (int a = 0; a < bit3.Count; a++)
    {
        listBox3.Items.Add(bit3[a]);
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < bit1.Count; a++)
    {
        listBox4.Items.Add(bit1[a]);
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < bit2.Count; a++)
    {
        listBox5.Items.Add(bit2[a]);
    }
}
```

`listBox4` gives the following output:

```
false, false, true, false
```

now in `listBox4` I think the correct output is as following because i don't change anything in bit1 array:

```
true, false, true, false
```

So what is the problem with `bit1` array ?

Comment: What does listBox1 return?

Comment: `True, False, True, False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The And method mutates (i.e. alters the object) the BitArray. From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.and%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the return value of BitArray.And:

> [Returns] [t]he current instance containing the result of the bitwise
>   AND operation on the elements in the current BitArray against the
>   corresponding elements in the specified BitArray.

Note that is says *the current instance*.

The `bit1` array will be the same instance as the `bit3` array. And as they are the same instance `listBox3` and `listBox4` will have the same values.

Edit: formatting and clarification

Comment: @Jonathon agreed, although quite common when it comes to this kind of low level stuff, especially in linear algebra libs. Very error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

You manipualted the BitArray bit1

```
BitArray bit3 = bit1.And(bit2);
```

*"Performs the bitwise AND operation on the elements in the current BitArray against the corresponding elements in the specified BitArray."*
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.bitarray.and.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I understood problem. BitArray is a mutable type.